# Solr: nested query referencing itself

Tags: solr

I'm new-ish with Solr, and I've been looking for this answer but not quite finding it... if there's already an answer please share!

Easiest way to explain what I'm going for, in brief :

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, (SELECT b.id, b.name) AS rel
FROM table_a AS a
JOIN table_b AS b ON b.name LIKE a.name;
```

Easy peasy.

So, say I have these three documents :

```
{ id : 1, name : "Robert" }
{ id : 2, name : "Jeffrey" }
{ id : 3, name : "Rob" }
```

What I'm looking for is a result like this :

```
[
    {
       id : 1,
       name : "Robert",
       rel : {
           id : 3,
           name : "Rob"
       }
    },
    {
       id : 3,
       name : "Rob",
       rel : {
           id : 1,
           name : "Robert"
       }
    }
]
```

I'll be ordering on another field to remove redundancy, but I'm sure you get the idea... unless there's already a way built into Solr to do that?

I've seen a few examples of nested queries, but each example has the values hardcoded - I need the nested query to be finding related documents based on the parent document's field value, for each document.

What's the magic word? In my case it will be the difference between 1 query and 20,000 + queries (doing a seperate name:"value"~1 query on every doc), I'd like to avoid that!

Answer (score 0):

This does not feel like the best use of Solr. Perhaps the original use-case can be better implemented in a different way.

The nearest available method is probably [[subquery] document transformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Transforming+Result+Documents#TransformingResultDocuments-[subquery]). It is available in the 6.2 Solr.